# Find the characteristic Polynomial for problem 1

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Can someone explain how I find the characteristic polynomial for one of these? I can find the multiplicity and determine if it is diagonalizable, but I am not sure how to do a.).

Comment: Do you know how to compute a $3 \times 3$ determinant? Then compute $\det(M - \lambda I)$

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic polynomial is calculate by solving:

$\det(A-\lambda \cdot I) = \begin{bmatrix} 4&-2&3 \\ 2&0&3 \\ -3 &3&-1 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0&0 \\ 0&\lambda&0 \\ 0&0&\lambda \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}(4-\lambda)&-2&3 \\ 2&-\lambda&3 \\ -3&3&(-1 -\lambda) \end{bmatrix} $

$= -\lambda^3 + 3\lambda^2 - 4$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the definition of characteristic polynomial. Call the matrix in (a) $A$, then you must find:

$$ \operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I),$$

which is a polynomial of the variable $\lambda$, i.e.:

$$-\lambda^3 +3\lambda^2 -4 $$

Answer (score 0):

For example, for a), compute the deterimnant of
$$\begin{pmatrix}4-x&-2&3\\2&-x&3\\-3&3&-1-x \end{pmatrix}$$

This gives you a third-degree polynomial on $x$. The degree matches with the dimension of the matrix.

Note that we have sum $-x$ to each term in the main diagonal. This is the same as susbstracting the matrix $xI_3$, where $x$ is an indeterminate and $I_3$ is the $3\times 3$ identity matrix. In other words, the characteristic polynomial of a $n\times n$ square matrix $A$ is
$$\det(A-xI_n)$$

*Note*: in this context is customary use the letter $\lambda$ instead of $x$.